# I'm currently going for a major in human computer interaction. Would anybody say that bootcamp is necessary after college?

Tags: education, continuing-education

I'm well aware of the importance of learning the software as well as the soft skills needed to become a ux designer, however I'm not sure if bootcamp or obtaining something like the google ux certificate would be 100% necessary. If someone could provide some insight into this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, at least one person would say a bootcamp is necessary.

Comment: Bootcamp in what? What does your education cover? What do you think is missing for the job you want?

Comment: Most IT certificates are not worth the time to earn them. The only exception is when a company actually requires it.

Answer (score 4):

Having both a Bachelors (Economics) and a Boot Camp Completion Certificate (Machine Learning/Data Analytics) I can confidently say that attending a bootcamp in the same discipline after receiving a degree is almost certainly not worth the money and the effort.

A bootcamp is similar to a highly accelerated set of courses for a major (lacking the gen-ed credits and elective options), which is designed to present, but not teach, information in a subject. A degree, on the other hand, aims to produce a well-rounded individual with a focus in the subject matter.

While I don't know the specifics of the UX design field, certificates in specific programs are usually a situational extra that can open some doors or potentially raise pay. One of the most obvious examples of this is found with industrial robot programmers. They don't need a certification to get a job, but being certified with a specific brand of robot does open some doors, and definitely gives you more negotiating power WRT wage.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your college department.

There should be an office at your college to help students find jobs after graduation. They can also help find internships. They can also provide resume assistance.

The school or the department should be holding job fairs every semester. Talk to the employers at those job fairs.

If you need a certificate in addition to your degree they would know.

Comment: I'm afraid our trust in colleges may be misplaced. In my experiences many colleges (at least in the US) these days do a depressingly poor job in preparing students for the workplace. Instead they focus on the "student experience".

Comment: Depends on the school, @Hilmar. Sometimes depends on the department, or graduate vs undergrad. It's certainly worth checking what resources are available.

Comment: Hence my use of "many" not "all". Its certainly worth checking what they got, but I would also look at their placement rates and first year success rates to check if its any good.